# Docker - The moduleSpecifier "..." couldn't be found on local disk

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I cannot mount a local folder to a docker volume on docker-compose
so it is not accessible on docker-compose run cmd.

Here is a repo from the github https://github.com/up1/demo-k6-docker

When I follow readme on `docker-compose run k6 run scripts/sample.js` it  gives me the following error all the time:

`WARN[0000] The moduleSpecifier "scripts/sample.js" has no scheme but we will try to resolve it as remote module. This will be deprecated in the future and all remote modules will need to explicitly use "https" as scheme.  ERRO[0000] The moduleSpecifier "scripts/sample.js" couldn't be found on local disk. Make sure that you've specified the right path to the file. If you're running k6 using the Docker image make sure you have mounted the local directory (-v /local/path/:/inside/docker/path) containing your script and modules so that they're accessible by k6 from inside of the container, see https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules#using-local-modules-with-docker. Additionally it was tried to be loaded as remote module by prepending "https://" to it, which also didn't work. Remote resolution error: "Get "https://scripts/sample.js": dial tcp: lookup scripts on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"`

Tried:

- specifically sharing folder in docker app settings window,
- different github repos,
- different mac laptops,
- different setups Dockerfile copy and -v option on docker run
- looking for similar questions
  and docs
  https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules#using-local-modules-with-docker

I would really appreciate some help, banging my head against the wall for a couple of days with this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
docker-compose run k6 run //scripts//sample.js
```

I'm running on docker desktop version 3.1.0 Windows 10 pro.

[Solution](https://community.k6.io/t/docker-compose-stopped-working-with-0-30-0/1297/7)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm solving issue in this and my personal project!

Comment: This solves the issue in WSL2 as well which I didn't think would be affected. Thanks a bunch.